# How to give different access to customer groups in bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have three customers group and I want different access for them like:

1. **Public**:
   This customer group is the non registered visitor of the website.
   They view the price as "Log in for price"
   They can not add to shopping cart, can not check out, can not make payments
2. **Registered not authorized**:
   This category is where all new registrations are assigned,
   Instead of " Log in for price" they see "Authorization Pending"
   This customer group can not add to shopping cart, can not check out
   The "Authorization Pending" to be on Product Search, Quick View, actual product page, etc
3. **Members**:
   This customer groups have full access, can view prices, can add to cart, can place orders, can make payments

So kindly tell me how can I give different access to these groups, so that public users and unauthorized users cannot add to cart etc.